# Update Set<Person> if Person exists, or add them if they don't

Tags: java, set, java-stream

Let's say I have a very simple class, Person, which contains a name and address:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String address;

    public Person(final String name,
                  final String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String address() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(final String newAddress) {
        this.address = newAddress;
    }
}
```

I now have a Set containing all of the known Person objects, and I want to update the address of one of the persons based only on their name.  For that I have the following:

```
persons.stream()
       .filter(person -> personToUpdate.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(person.getName()))
       .forEach(person -> {
                person.setAddress(personToUpdate.getAddress());
        });
```

However, my problem is when I have a new person altogether who is not in the Set.  How do I check the Set to see if the person exists, and if so, update their address.  But if they don't exist, add them to the list.  I know this is simple, but for whatever reason I just cannot think how to achieve this right now.  I do not want to go down the road of creating a List of all the names, comparing the new name, if they're in the list etc etc etc.  I'd rather keep it as concise as possible.

EDIT: Names will be unique!

Comment: Any reason it has to be a `Set` as opposed to, let's say, a `Map`?

Comment: Will there only ever be zero or one matching `Person`, or could there be more than one? Also, you don't appear to have implemented `equals` or `hashCode` on `Person`, so how does your `Set` differentiate `Person` objects? Just by reference equality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you need a one-liner, you can simply take advantage of the of the `Optional`s:

```
Optional<Person> person = persons.stream()
        .filter(p -> personToUpdate.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getName()))
        .findFirst();

if (person.isPresent()) {
    person.get().setAddress(personToUpdate.getAddress());
} else {
    persons.add(personToUpdate);
}
```

If you're using Java 9+, this can look even better:

```
persons.stream()
        .filter(p -> personToUpdate.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getName()))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresentOrElse(
            p -> p.setAddress(personToUpdate.getAddress()),
            () -> persons.add(personToUpdate)
        );
```

This of course assumes that names are unique (as you expect to update one entry).

Comment: updating the list while using a stream of it just looks off, shouldn't that be avoided?

Comment: I mean, the JIT will probably optimize away the allocation of the `Optional` instances here, but is this really better than the dead-simple way using a `for` loop? It's just as many if not more lines of code, and it is also dense to the point of being almost incomprehensible at first glance, with no practical benefit to make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like so by using a `Map`.

```
Map<String, Person> personMap = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
personMap.merge(personToUpdate.getName(), personToUpdate, 
    (p1, p2) -> new Person(p1.getName(), p2.address()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few easy ways to do this (I'm assuming that name uniquely identifies a Person, and two Person objects with the same name are considered equal)

1. Implement `equals` and `hashcode`, and do a `contains` call before your stream - if it returns false, it's not in the set
2. Use a `Map` instead of a `Set`, where the key can be easily used to lookup a person by an attribute (like name, which seems to be your primary key here).

Side note - you should implement `equals` and `hashcode` anyways - especially if you're putting these objects into a `Set` or `Map`. By  implementing `equals` and `hashcode` to only consider name, you will guarantee uniqueness of name within the set (right now it's not guaranteed)

Comment: Note that OP only has a name to go on, so `equals` and `hashCode` might not work so well here.

Comment: In this system, are two `Person` objects equal if they have the same name but different address? Based on how they want to use `Person`, it seems this is the case. Not saying it's the best way to do it (it's why real people have other differentiating factors, like SSN)

Comment: No unfortunately not.  I need to check if the Set has a Person object that contains the same name as the one I need to update.

Comment: _I need to check if the Set has a Person object that contains the same name as the one I need to update_ -- that's exactly what I mean - if you find a `Person` with the matching name, it equals the one you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (1) your `Person` objects are intended to only be compared using reference equality (and thus that object identity needs to be preserved), and (2) multiple `Person` objects might match a given name, you'll need to handle these cases manually:

```
public static void updatePersonAddress(String name, String address, Set<Person> persons) {
    // Find all the matching persons, if any.
    List<Person> matched = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person person : persons) {
        if (person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            matched.append(person);
        }
    }

    // If zero persons matched, create a new Person to match,
    // and add the new person to the set. Then we're done!
    if (matched.isEmpty()) {
        persons.add(new Person(name, address));
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, update the Person objects (which are still in the
    // persons Set) to include the new address.
    for (Person person : matched) {
        person.setAddress(address);
    }
}
```

If names are unique, this simplifies to:

```
public static void updatePersonAddress(String name, String address, Set<Person> persons) {
    for (Person person : persons) {
        if (person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            person.setAddress(address);
            // If we've found one that matches, then we know there
            // won't be any more, so we can be done now.
            return;
        }
    }
    // If we made it through the loop without returning, then it means
    // that no Person in the Set matched. So add one that does.
    persons.add(new Person(name, address));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use persons.contains(person). However you will have to override hashcode() and equals() methods